# How can I execute cakephp shell via cronjob in a different PHP-Version?

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0

We are using Cakephp V2.10.3. In our Crontab we want to run a cakephp shell command in PHP V5.6. This PHP-Version is located in `/opt/plesk/php/php5.6/bin/php`.

The Cronjob executes the following shell command:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/apps/MyProject/app && Console/cake DoSomething
```

The PHP code in 'DoSomething' logs the PHP Version into a file using `phpversion()`.

**Problem:** The Log shows the following PHP-Version: **5.4.45**-0+deb7u11

In the File app/Console/cakephp we replaced the first line by the following line:

```
#!/opt/plesk/php/php5.6/bin/php -q
```

But when we run the cronjob again, the log still shows PHP V5.4.

How can we run the cronjob in PHP 5.6?

Comment: Try looking at this answer might be relevant https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php

Comment: @Derek: Thank you very much for your answer. Good to know. But unfortunately, this article does not solve the Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to change at "app/Console/cake"

the line

```
exec php -q .....
```

to

```
exec /opt/plesk/php/php5.6/bin/php -q -d register_argc_argv=1 .....
```

Additional informations:

PHP - reference: => http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv